# mysql syntax create syntax error cannot find

Tags: mysql

```
create table if not exists order(
orderID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
ordertype int, 
productID int,
pname varchar(20),
company varchar(20), 
vari varchar(20), 
price int);
```

error log:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(orderID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,ordertype int, productID i' at line 1

Comment: `order` is a reserved word (it's used in `ORDER BY`), you need to quote it with backticks.

Comment: It's the `PRIMARY_KEY`, change it to `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: thankyou both it solved my problem